# How to print a number in Arm Assembly on Mac M1

Tags: macos, assembly, arm64

I am new to arm assembly and have been teaching myself from online resources. I am not able to figure out how to print a number while trying to code the classic FizzBuzz problem.
This is my code:

```
.global _start
.align 2

_start:
mov w5, #0

    loop:
    mov w3, #15
    sdiv w6, w5, w3
    mul w6, w6, w3
    sub w6, w5, w6 
    cmp w6, #0
    b.eq _print_fizzbuzz
    
    mov w3, #3
    sdiv w6, w5, w3
    mul w6, w6, w3
    sub w6, w5, w6 
    cmp w6, #0
    b.eq _print_fizz
    
    mov w3, #5
    sdiv w6, w5, w3
    mul w6, w6, w3
    sub w6, w5, w6 
    cmp w6, #0
    b.eq _print_buzz 
    
    b _print_number
    
    comparison:
    cmp w5, #50
    add w5, w5, #1
    b.ne loop
    
    mov x0, #0   //return 0
    mov x16, #1  //terminate
    svc 0x80  //syscall

_print_fizzbuzz:
mov x0, #1
adrp x1, fb@page
add x1, x1, fb@pageoff
mov x2, #9
mov x16, #4
svc 0
b comparison

_print_fizz:
mov x0, #1
adrp x1, fizz@page
add x1, x1, fizz@pageoff
mov x2, #5
mov x16, #4
svc 0
b comparison

_print_buzz:
mov x0, #1
adrp x1, buzz@page
add x1, x1, buzz@pageoff
mov x2, #5
mov x16, #4
svc 0
b comparison

_print_number:
mov x0, #1
adrp x1, num@page
add x1, x1, num@pageoff
mov x2, #4
mov x16, #4
svc 0
b comparison

.data
fb: .asciz "FizzBuzz\n"
fizz: .asciz "Fizz\n"
buzz: .asciz "Buzz\n"
num: .asciz "Num\n"
```

I have been printing 'Num' for the numbers since I couldn't figure out how to print the number and just wanted an output that worked. The code might be inefficient, but I have been only been learning since the last 2-3 weeks.

I have tried using printf but the linker was giving me an issue. I have also gone through many posts here and other sites which didn't help me. Even using ChatGPT wasn't fruitful.
The main problem for me has been that there aren't many resources that I could find to learn assembly on Macs.
Anyone who could help with this would be great and if you can recommend any good resources to learn assembly on Mac other than [HelloWorld](https://github.com/below/HelloSilicon?tab=readme-ov-file) please do let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ChatGPT is pretty useless for assembly questions.  I recommend you ignore it.  To call printf, you'll have to link through the C compiler and ensure the libc gets initialised.  The way you are currently programming, you'll not be able to call libc functions.  If you want to do it without libc, you'll have to manually implement a routine to convert integers to strings for printing.

Comment: Now if you want to link in the libc, you need to (a) start your program at `_main`, not `_start`.  (b) exit the program by returning from `_main` or calling `_exit`, not by doing a raw syscall (otherwise buffers will not be flushed) and (c) link with the C compiler.

Comment: Regardless of what you want to do, you can always write a C implementation and use `clang -O3 -S` to look at the assembly it generates. As for the number thing... char buffer, loop, modulo 10.

Comment: @fuz these are the following commands that I use to compile and link the code:
```as fizzbuzz.s -o fizzbuzz.o 
ld fizzbuzz.o -o fb -lSystem -syslibroot `xcrun -sdk macosx --show-sdk-path` -e _start -arch arm64```
Can you let me know how can I modify the linking command so that libc gets initialised. Also what would changes would the code require for it to work with printf.

Comment: @Pranay Follow the instructions above, then assemble and link with `cc -o fb fizzbuzz.s`.